# Angular Material Custom Component Theming - bundle size optimisation

Tags: angular, angular-material2

This question is related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070995/angular-material-custom-component-theming/52537633#52537633). The main goal is to find best way to optimize bundle size of themed components.

Well, we have a theme like this:

```
amber
  ├ _variables.scss
  ├ theme.scss
```

`_variables.scss`:

```
$amber-primary: mat-palette($orange);
$amber-accent:  mat-palette($orange, A700, A100, A400);
$amber-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red, A200);
$amber-theme:   mat-light-theme($amber-primary, $amber-accent, $amber-warn);
```

`theme.scss`:

```
.amber-theme {
    @include angular-material-theme($amber-theme);
}
```

And in the parent folder there's some `_variables` file to gather all colors and themes together:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import 'colors';

@import 'amber/variables';
...
```

Looks cool, right? BUT! If you bundle this with `scss-bundler` and create your own library it still should be not big at all (I've got 11 Kb for ~14 themes). When you include your `styles.scss` with all themes - it works as expected and everything should be fine.

The problems appears when you want to customize some component. Icluding `styles.scss` is really bad idea, as related answer says, and it's true - got ~2,68 Mb per themed component. But including `_variales.scss` providing too much aswell - 260 Kb per themed component still a big deal. I've research generated code and discovered that `'~@angular/material/theming` included for each themed component. Well, this should be right for Angular way of isolating styles for components, and I can't just drop this file, because there's related mixins, but maybe there's some another way to make this file global and do not include it into each and every component I want to customize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to include 14 themes(Which I have no idea why you want to do that) and reduce the initial css file size you can do what the [Angular Material documentation site](https://material.angular.io/) do (Repo [link](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io)).

By having a style manager service and removing and including the style and fetch a different css file (Http req) each time the user changes theme. Here are the few key files you can look out for you to understand how they do it.

**Services that help with it.**

`<repo_root>/src/app/shared/theme-picker/`

`<repo_root>/src/app/shared/style-manager/`

**How they compile the custom themes**

`<repo_root>/tools/build-themes.sh`

**Where the custom themes are located**

`material.angular.io/src/assets/`